# CS0103 This name '' does not exist in the current context

Tags: asp.net-core

I've got this class:

```
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context,
    TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        if (ViewContext != null && PageModel != null)
        {
            IUrlHelper urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
            TagBuilder result = new TagBuilder("div");
            for (int i = 1; i <= PageModel.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
                tag.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(PageAction,
                new { productPage = i });
            }
            tag.InnerHtml.Append(i.ToString());
            result.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(tag);
        }
        output.Content.AppendHtml(result.InnerHtml);
    }
```

However, the 'tag', 'i' and 'result' attributes after the for-loop don't fall in the scope, which shouldn't be the matter if I'm correct. I'm using VS2022 with SDK version 6.0.402.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want in the end, but one thing you should pay attention to is that variables defined in a `for` loop can only be used in a `for` loop, and variables defined in an `if` can only be used in an `if`.

So `tag.InnerHtml.Append(i.ToString());` can only be used in a for loop, unless you define an `i` outside the for loop. Like this:

```
int k = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= PageModel.TotalPages; i++)
{
    k=i;//The final value of k is PageModel.TotalPages.Count
}
tag.InnerHtml.Append(k.ToString());
```

If you want to add all `i` in `TagBuilder tag`, then it should be like this:

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context,
    TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        TagBuilder result = new TagBuilder("div");
        if (ViewContext != null && PageModel != null)
        {
            IUrlHelper urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
            for (int i = 1; i <= PageModel.TotalPages; i++)
            { 
                tag.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(PageAction,
                new { productPage = i });
                tag.InnerHtml.Append(i.ToString());
            }
            result.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(tag);
        }
        output.Content.AppendHtml(result.InnerHtml);
    }
```

If you only want to add the last entry of `PageModel.TotalPages` in the `TagBuilder tag`, it should be like this:

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context,
   TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        TagBuilder result = new TagBuilder("div");
        if (ViewContext != null && PageModel != null)
        {
            IUrlHelper urlHelper = UrlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
            TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
            for (int i = 1; i <= PageModel.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                tag = new TagBuilder("a");
                tag.Attributes["href"] = urlHelper.Action(PageAction,
                new { productPage = i });
                tag.InnerHtml.Append(i.ToString());
            }
            result.InnerHtml.AppendHtml(tag);

        }
        output.Content.AppendHtml(result.InnerHtml);
    }
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clearing that up! :D

Comment: Hi @Omid Noor, If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer? Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry man, I totally forgot about that!